# Is there any way to get Uninstalling event when my android/ios app is getting uninstalled by the user in cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am using cordova to build ios/android application. I want to know whenever my apps getting uninstalled, this is the requirement from my client. Is there any way to identify uninstalling event using cordova?

Comment: For native apps, you can use push notifications to do this. See https://leftshift.io/mobile-tracking-uninstalls-on-ios-and-android. The same trick might work with Cordova.

Comment: You can not listen to your app uninstallation. Instead you can listen to uninstallation of other apps from your app.

Comment: Thank you @BrettDonald for your quick response. I hope that will work in my case, anyway I will workout that.

Comment: For native apps,Firebase also provides uninstall tracking by default